# prevent applying previous page CSS to next page when it navigates with ajax pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, axios

I've written a messages table and I get it's data to show in my site with Vue-js + Axios , I also use pagination , if a row will be unread I show it with Bold stylesheet afetr reading it's CSS will be clean.

in page 1 everything is okay, but when i want to navigate to next page current page stylesheet transfers to next page and i don't want to send previous page effects to next page.

For example:
Second row of First page is unread with Bold tag
And
Second row of Second page is also unread

when I read Second row of First page it's Bold tag will removed
and when I navigate to next page I see Second row of Second page is also read ( without any Bold tag)

everything is ok in Database but when table will be render and navigate in front end table css property transfer among pages!!

I've used vue js 2.5 + laravel + axios

```
<tbody id="tbody_1">
<tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :class="[ item.is_read == 0 ? 'bold' : '']" :id="'rowId'+item.id">
    <td @click="editItem(item.id)">@{{ item.subject }}</td>
</tr>
```

```
editItem: function(id){
    var self = this;
    axios.get(self.ApiUrl+'/'+id+'/edit').then(function (response) {
        $('tr#rowId'+id).removeClass('bold');
    });
},
```

Comment: You are not showing us the right part of your code. Can you post a bigger snippet of your jQuery including the pagination part?

Comment: Instead of doing `editItem(item.id)`, why not just do `editItem(item)`.  And now that you have item in your function, simply: `item.is_read = 1` and let the Vue handle class binding.

Comment: If you use vue to add class, don't use jQuery to remove said class... just mark your `item.is_read = true` and it should not be bold